# Prevent rspec from running migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005

I have a rails app with a sql server database. I manually create an empty database for rspec to test on with all the necessary tables before running the specs. Currently when running the specs the database will have its tables drop as the rails migrations are empty. I need rspec to messing with the tables is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have a feeling that your issue is probally better solved by turning on SQL schema dumps and dumping the schema so that Rails can automatically create it for you.